# AngularJS consumir RESTful em dominios diferentes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-service, restful, angularjs-services

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer um cliente que indexa as informações de vários webservices (sobre cotações de bitcoin de várias corretoras) porém ao tentar acessar o webservice os valores importados do json não são exibidos, e ao apertar o F12 no chrome retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

já dei uma pesquisada sobre o erro, o mesmo tbm ocorre no meu servidor de testes remoto (hostinger), eu sei que o erro ocorre porque o servidor não retorna a header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *" porém são muitos servidores diferentes de terceiros que eu irei buscar e todos me retornam este mesmo erro...

segue o código utilizado para acessar o WS:
(serviço)

```js
app.factory('foxbit', ['$http', 
function($http){ 
 return $http.get('https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC')
 .success(function(data) {
   return data;
 })
 .error(function(err) {
   return err;
 });
}]);
```

Controller:

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'foxbit', function($scope, foxbit) {
  foxbit.success(function(data) {
    $scope.cotacaofox = data;
  });
  
}]);
```

Então, se os ninjas daqui puderem me indicar um meio de contornar este erro, eu ficarei muito grato.

Obrigado.

Comment: já tentou criar um virtual host pra ver se você contorna o problema?
Dica: Não deixe o 'succes' e o 'error' na factory. Você deve tratar isso no controller. E ao invés de usar essas funções para tratar o retorno, use 'then'. As duas anteriores parecem que estão 'deprecated'.

Comment: O problema do virtual host é que eu vou colocar a página em um servidor remoto que não tenho acesso a essa customização no servidor remoto, e quanto ao success e ao error, eu coloquei só pq fica mais fácil, mais pretendo arrumar antes de colocar em produção..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa é uma limitação imposta pelo CORS. Duas possibilidades:

- Solicite aos mantenedores do serviço blinktrade.com que incluam o seu domínio de origem na lista de domínios autorizados, ou
- Implemente um serviço de proxy local, eliminando a avaliação do CORS.

Um exemplo de *proxy* em C#/WebApi 2 vem a seguir:

```
[RoutePrefix("stack/proxy")]
public class ProxyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public object Search([FromUri] string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var result = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
            };

            return resp;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

> http://localhost:49801/stack/proxy/?url=https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC

Resultado:

```
{
"high":1693.88,
"vol":248.24057349,
"buy":1623.55,
"last":1623.54,
"low":1551.01,
"pair":"BTCBRL",
"sell":1625.11,
"vol_brl":403631.3524226
}
```

Código-fonte para controller WebApi retirado do [projeto Nyan (gitHub)](https://github.com/bucknellu/Nyan/blob/6c125ec3526483d9e3f26c9b3248595b46e6e295/Modules/Web/REST/tools/Proxy.cs).

Comment: Igual eu falei acima, não tenho como pedir para os mantenedores do WS adicionar o tratamento ao header do response pq são vários WS que eu vou buscar informações...

Comment: Por isso a sugestão de implementar um proxy service local, Dennis. CORS só influencia requisições XHR entre domínios. Uma chamada via proxy funciona como uma requisição direta.

Comment: @Dennis Uma alternativa é fazer as requisicoes utilizando jsonp. Essa funcionalidade se aplica apenas para Get e internamente cria um elemento script que pode referenciar outro dominio. Um parâmetro a mais será necessario para possibilitar a injeçao de callback. Favor pesquisar a documentacao. $Http.jsonp

Comment: O problema do JSONP é que nos WS que eu estou consumindo nenhum deles retorna os dados em JSONP somente em JSON.